# Handling transactional resources in reactive way

Tags: transactions, akka, distributed, reactive-programming

I'm about to start a new project in financial area, where global and distributed transaction are currently rule the world, however in reactive world where things are done in different threads and actors asynchronously classic approach won't work.
Here is an example. Let's say we have IBM MQ consumer receiving messages, this guy reside in separate actor. Also we transfer each message to another actor which does some business logic or simply store it in other transactional datasource like Oracle DB.
Now in case of disaster or exception in business logic i need to roll back the MQ transaction and so message will be polled again after recovery.
How transactional data sources are handled in reactive world? I'm looking in STM and seems it solves the problem, the only thing is that i have to explicitly handle exceptions (through supervising in akka) and rollback transaction in case of any. However i can see violation of reactive way of doing things, the MQ consumer actor MUST WAIT (block?!) until exception or success confirmation received from another actor (business logic or other transactional datasource) and commit or rollback MQ transaction. Is it correct understanding or i'm missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a distributed transaction coordinator for this. In .NET, the TransactionScope would help. (ODP.NET and MSMQ support transactionscope).
You might want to use this concept with the Unit of work design pattern.

Also have a look at this article: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotnetrodent/archive/2008/04/16/121279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but I've been thinking about it some time and in my belief IBM MQ or Oracle are not ready for it because they lack non blocking APIs.

If you look at db transaction in oracle it is associated with connection, so in "reactive way" you need put connection aside (without commiting) and at some point receive an event telling you to commit or rollback. While events intend to flow quite fast you will end up with lots of open connections. Connections are heavy, it will probably kill your database, where one connection == one session in database. Sessions in oracle are quite heavy. 
Same applies for WebSphere MQ. I think that when you are forced to use technologies like Oracle or MQ, there is no point in going reactive. You can speed up your application, but usually in business apps requiring such strict transactions your bottleneck will lie in Oracle anyway.
Good news is Oracle is working on non-blocking apis...